# KQL Query Structure doing searches in code

Tags: search, keywordquery

I want to build a KQL query for some server side code to search both custom properties and document content. So if for example there was a property called reference and we are looking for content say "affiliated" I have tried something like:

Reference: "1234" and affiliated

But the query returns items with the terms Reference and affiliated in it. It looks like the reference property is being applied as well so I am just getting a subset of my results.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have spent some time with this and it's a reasonably complex area but. I have discovered (DOH!) that I need to be using the Managed Property name in the KQL Search. So when the crawler crawls and finds a document property, column, etc. It creates a crawled property it also creates a mapped Managed Property.

So when building your KQL you need to know what the Managed property name is, in the case of Reference it will be **ReferenceOWSTEXT** this includes the name (note spaces will be removed for properties that have those) OWS and finally the field type (in this case TEXT).

So my query now looks like **ReferenceOWSTEXT:"1234" affiliated** this brings back only documents that have a Reference field with the value 1234 and the text affiliated in the body; title or other properties of the document.

Hopefully this may help any others in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that case matters. In the search center try Reference:"1234" (the colon is a contains operator, if you want exactly "1234" use Reference="1234") that should only get the items for Reference. Confirm that is working first. Then add "affiliated AND " so that your whole query is `affiliated AND Reference="1234"`.

BTW, is the Reference managed property data type Text, Integer, or ??

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, tried the above with no luck. The Reference field is a string (text) type. I only get results if I put the query as 

1234 AND affiliated 

or

Comment: or ...

1234 affiliated

putting the field name in does not return anything unless that's in the document too.

Comment: I suspect that something is wrong with your managed property definition or that you have not completed a full crawl of the content.

Comment: Have looked at that, a full crawl has been done but it makes no difference. Will look at this further when I get chance. I have just specified the term as free text so "affiliated AND 1234" which is working for the time being. But I may need to revisit if the search terms increase.